# How to retrieve Goo.gl/maps link for a physical address

Tags: google-maps, sms

**Background**

I'm creating an app that will allow me to send meeting points to my clients by SMS. The meeting points are always physical addresses, not coordinates. When doing the process manually through Google Maps, it looks like so:

[image]

Note that the link generated is a goo.gl. Also, note the neatly generated thumbnail, displaying the facade of the house and the address under it. Very user friendly.

**My problem**

Trying to recreate the step above programmatically works only partially; it creates a workable link but the SMS does not display the facade picture of the house, nor is the address displayed below the thumbnail.

Most inquiries I found on the topic point to [Google's Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide), where they make use of the following synthax:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={{URL encoded address}}
```

or in this situation:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=172+Fourth+Ave+Ottawa%2C+ON+K1S+2L6
```

Following the approach above yields the following SMS:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to get the first output generated via goo.gl link?

Comment: Not sure, but probably [street view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#street-view-action) URL might give you a facade picture. But in this case you should find out a pano ID of your address. In order to get pano ID you can try [Street View Image Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) web service.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good approach actually. I'll look into it and post my solution shortly.